# Multiple instances of the same WCF service?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to run multiple instances of the same WCF service in Visual Studio 2012. The service needs to be stateful so I am using `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]`. The services needs to mimic server behaviour in that they must maintain state no matter which client connects to them.

How can I do this?

**--- EDIT ---**

An example:
There's three instances of the service called Shop1, Shop2 and Shop3. Each have their own balance as a "state". Client1 and Client2 now buys something from Shop1, which involves increasing the balance of Shop1. Client 3 purchases something from Shop2 which increases it's balance.

The intention is that Shop1, Shop2 and Shop3 are hosted on different machines, but for testing purposes I would like to run them on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use callback model against two-way, you will can process more clients

or

set `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]` and save state in static properties

---

```
var serviseHost1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(Shop));
serviseHost1.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Shop), binding, endpoint);
serviseHost1.Open();
var serviseHost2 = new ServiceHost(typeof(Shop));
serviseHost2.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Shop), binding, endpoint);
serviseHost2.Open();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first option?
I don't think the second option would work. I need different clients to be able to connect to the same instance of the service with the same state. PerCall would create one instance per service if I undertand correctly?

Comment: please explain what are you mean by state

Comment: I added an example to the original post. PerCall would not maintain the balance of the Shops between the different clients as it is stored in memory.

Comment: start few instance, that's all, if your application hosted in iis add few svc files, if your application is selfhosted open service host at few endpoints

Comment: It is selfhosted. But what if I want to run - 50 instances? 
Adding endpoints only provides a different way to access the same service right?

Comment: no, you must not add endpoints only, start service at new enpoints, i add sample to answer

Comment: Thank you very much. This does what I want.